# getting error when calculating loss - unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, loss-function, mse

I am trying to calculating loss using the below code

```
class MSE_gradient(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MSE_gradient, self).__init__()

  def forward(self,inputs, targets):
    diff = torch.gradient(inputs) - torch.gradient(targets)
    return torch.sum(diff*diff)/diff.numel()
```

but i am getting error

```
      6   def forward(self,inputs, targets):
----> 7     diff = torch.gradient(inputs) - torch.gradient(targets)
      8     return torch.sum(diff*diff)/diff.numel()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

I am trying to calculate the gradient of image and find MSE error of it. please help

Comment: try printing `torch.gradient(inputs)`

Comment: [Link](https://pastebin.com/hJRWDJ6c) out put of `torch.gradient(inputs)`

Answer (score 1):

`torch.gradient` outputs a tuple as you can see and you cannot subtract one tuple from another elementwise, hence the error.

Instead of `diff = torch.gradient(inputs) - torch.gradient(targets)`, use

```
diff = [] 
for a, b in zip (torch.gradient(inputs), torch.gradient(targets)):
    diff.append(a-b)

# if you need tuple, cast diff as tuple
diff = tuple(diff)
```